# Submit initial value when using Javascript number formatting

Tags: javascript, formatting, form-submit, nouislider

I'm using number formatting (wNumb) for a text field. It gets updated by the range slider (noUislider) and that works fine.

The issue I'm experiencing is that **when I submit the form**, **the saved value is divided by 1000** (probably due to the thousands separator).

**How could I get rid of wNumb formatting when submitting?**

```
...
<%= f.text_field :salary, id: "how-much" %>

 <div id="slider-format"></div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

Then the script below :

```
<script>
var sliderFormat = document.getElementById('slider-format');

noUiSlider.create(sliderFormat, {
    start: [ 200000 ],
    step: 1000,
  connect: 'upper',
    range: {
        'min': [ 10000 ],
        'max': [ 250000 ],
    },
  format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
        thousand: '.',
        postfix: ' (US $)',
    })
});

var inputValue = document.getElementById('how-much');

sliderFormat.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    inputValue.value = values[handle];
});

inputValue.addEventListener('change', function(){
    sliderFormat.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
});
</script>
```

The instructions on http://refreshless.com/wnumb/ are the following... I don't understand how to use that if this is what I should use.

```
Usage
var moneyFormat = wNumb({
    mark: '.',
    thousand: ',',
    prefix: '$ ',
    postfix: ' p.p.'
});

// Format a number:
moneyFormat.to( 301980.62 );
=> '$ 301,980.62 p.p.'

// Get a number back:
moneyFormat.from( '$ 301,980.62 p.p.' );
    => 301980.62
```

Comment: Clarifying doubts - do you want to submit vaue as `301980.62` instead of `$ 301,980.62 p.p.`? Or if your formatter not working properly?

Comment: I would like the user to set 301980, this would get displayed as $ 301.980, but when clicking submit button of the form, getting 301980 again. For the moment I'm getting 301 in the database...

The last block of code is not from me, it's from the documentation and I don't know how to use that with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While saving value to input you need to add numbers only to some attribute of input tag.

```
sliderFormat.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
  inputValue.value = values[handle];
  $(inputValue).attr("actual", parseFloat(values[handle]).toString().replace('.',''));
});
```

And then you can replace value with attr `actual` while submitting form.

```
$("form").on("submit",function() {
  $("#how-much").val($("#how-much").attr("actual"));
});
```

I hope this works as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the meantime I made a loop which is working too

how-much is now hidden.

slider updates -> how-much
how-much updates -> a new field called "displayed"
displayed updates -> slider

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the issue with thousand property, you are giving . instead of ,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but , instead of . doesn't change anything to the issue.